# Permanently delete a version of an MLFlow Model

Tags: mlflow

In MLFlow, when a new version of a model is pushed, its version is automatically incremented by 1.
If we delete version 14 and push a new version, the new version of the model will be 15 even though version 14 has been deleted.

I want to permanently delete a version of an MLFlow Model so that when I push a new version of the model the new version number is the one of the previously deleted model.

Answer (score 0):

While I can not speak specifically for `MLFlow` the approach to most cloud, source control, and messaging systems is to ensure immutability as an absolutely vital tenet. One of the strategies is to never reuse identifiers. Therefore, it is doubtful that reusing an MLFlow Model identifier would be allowed/possible.